# Vector input gives output vector `[0,...,0]` in Python

Tags: python, vector

I'm trying to create a vector class in Python. I'm not so far yet, and stuck already.

This is my current code:

```
    class vector:

        def __init__(self, n, l = []):
            self.v = []
            if(isinstance(n, int)):
               x = int(n)
               if (x < 0):
                   return SyntaxError
               else:
                   self.v += [0.0] * x
            else:
               self.v += n

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.v)
```

The problem is, that when my input is

```
    >>> u = vector(3,3.14)
    >>> print(u)
```

then my ouput is

```
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

But I want it to be

```
    [3.14,3.14,3.14]
```

and I also want the following:

```
    >>> v=[3,[2.0,3.14,-5])
    >>> print(v)
    [2.0,3.14,-5]
```

What is the problem in my script?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't use your argument `l` at all in your function. How then should the argument influence the returnvalue?

Comment: @syntonym you're right! I think I need to make a for-loop, but I'm not sure how.. `for i in range(len(l)):` and then do something. can you help me?

Comment: Why is `l` a list (as default) but you pass a float into the function in your example?

Answer (score 3):

You have `[0.0] * x`, but I think you mean `[l] * x`.

It really helps to clear up what kind of cases your code must support and write it down. It also helps to define a clear list of input and output combinations, you can use them as a test:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, n, l):
        if isinstance(l, (list, tuple)):  # l is a list, check length
            if len(l) == n:  # length as required, keep as is
                pass
            elif len(l) > n:  # to long, use only the first n items
                l = l[0:n]
            elif len(l) < n:  # to short, append zeros
                l += [0] * (n - len(l))

        elif isinstance(l, (int, float)):  # create a list containing n items of l
            l = [l] * n

        self.v = l

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.v)
```

Add some tests:

```
def test(a, b):
    print 'input: {}, output: {}'.format(a, b)
    if str(a) != b:
        print('Not equal!')

test(Vector(3, 3.14), '[3.14, 3.14, 3.14]')
test(Vector(3, [4, 4, 4]), '[4, 4, 4]')
test(Vector(2, [4, 4, 4]), '[4, 4]')
test(Vector(4, [4, 4, 4]), '[4, 4, 4, 0]')
test(Vector(3, [2.0, 3.14, -5]), '[2.0, 3.14, -5]')
```

Comment: Well, I thought it worked.. But when my input is `(3,[1,2,3])` then my output is `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`. How can I fix this?

Comment: yeah, that's what I would expect. What would you want to get back with input `(3, [1, 2, 3])`?

Maybe you should start by writing down (in a comment) what different inputs should result in what outputs.

Comment: input `(3,[1,2,3])`, output `[1,2,3]`. I wrote some inputs and outputs in my question. I also want `(4,[1,2,3])` output `[1,2,3,0]`. Do I make myself more clear now?\

Comment: So I see two cases: 1. `<int>n, <number>x -> [x, x, ...]` and 2. `<int>n, <list>l` should result in the origininal list `l` if `n == len(l)` or else it should make the list longer or shorter, correct?

Comment: @JBIBB added an example to the answer. Make sure to have a clear understanding of what you want/need, and add that to your questions here. Really helps when answering.